# Converting decimal hours to hours minutes and seconds

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Is there a more elegant solution to the following in xslt 1.0? I understand there are built in functions to xslt 2.0.

I'm taking a number in decimal hours and need to represent it as HH:MM:SS. At the moment I have the following which functions well.

```
<xsl:variable name="decimal_hours" select="pre_lab_cost div pre_labour_rate"/>
<xsl:variable name="decimal_minutes" select="number(concat('0.',substring-after($decimal_hours, '.')))*60"/>
<xsl:variable name="decimal_seconds" select="number(concat('0.',substring-after($decimal_minutes, '.')))*60"/>
<xsl:value-of select="concat(format-number(floor($decimal_hours), '00'),
                                           ':',
                                           format-number(floor($decimal_minutes), '00'),
                                           ':',
                                           format-number(floor($decimal_seconds), '00')
                                           )"/>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about this ...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:variable name="decimal_hours" select="3.14"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:value-of select="concat(
  format-number(floor($decimal_hours              ), '00:'),
  format-number(floor($decimal_hours *  60 mod  60), '00:'),
  format-number(floor($decimal_hours * 360 mod 360), '00'))"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I like it, Hadn't considered a mod which in hindsight was silly.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone had the issue I just had which the above answer was brilliant, but I needed to take Decimal MINUTES into hours:minutes:seconds.
so below is the breakdown to help with that if required, a little cut back...

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(
  format-number(floor($Decimal_Minutes div 60), '00:'),
  format-number(floor($Decimal_Minutes mod 60), '00:'),
  format-number(($Decimal_Minutes - floor($Decimal_Minutes)) * 60, '00'))"/>
```