# Using Arrays and adding elements in XSLT

Tags: xml, arrays, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have some variables which need to be compared and according if they are equal need to be added to an array my biggest problem is

a. is an array a good means for this

b. how would I add elements to an array

Also I think there will be a need for a lot of ifs right.

```
<xsl:variable name="Monday">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="./OpeningHours/Monday"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="Tuesday">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="OpeningHours/Tuesday"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="Wednesday">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="OpeningHours/Wednesday"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="Thursday">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="OpeningHours/Thursday"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="Friday">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="OpeningHours/Friday"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="Saturday">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="OpeningHours/Saturday"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="Sunday">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="OpeningHours/Sunday"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

template being applied

```
<xsl:template match="OpeningHours/*">
    <xsl:value-of select="Open + Close"/>
</xsl:template>
```

sample of data

```
<OpeningHours>
    <Monday>
        <Open>8.5</Open>
        <Close>20</Close>
    </Monday>
    <Tuesday>
        <Open>8.5</Open>
        <Close>20</Close>
    </Tuesday>
    <Wednesday>
        <Open>8.5</Open>
        <Close>20</Close>
    </Wednesday>
    <Friday>
        <Open>8.5</Open>
        <Close>22</Close>
    </Friday>
    <Saturday>
        <Open>7</Open>
        <Close>14</Close>
    </Saturday>
</OpeningHours>
```

my final result should be

Mon-Wed 8:30-20:00

Fri     8:30-22:00

Sat     7:00-14:00

Comment: I think you need to address three issues: a) An array like configuration for the days of the week to handle them in the right order and supplying the abbreviations required in the output. This can be handled by a node list in XSLT 2.0. b) You need grouping for identical opening hours. c) You need formatting for the time strings representing the opening hours.

Comment: One more remark: Do you have any influence on the input file format? If so, I would suggest to do away with the specific tags for each day of the week and simply move this piece of information to an attribute of a generic tag such as `<openingHoursOnDay day="NAME">`. This makes the handling much easier.

Comment: @MarcusRickert technically I do have control over the file although I think it might be better not to change now as the proposal has already been submitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using XSLT 2.0 I think this is a job for `for-each-group group-adjacent`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="OpeningHours">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="concat(Open, '|', Close)">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(local-name(), 1, 3),
                                 if (current-group()[2]) then concat('-', substring(local-name(current-group()[last()]), 1, 3)) else (),
                                 ' ', Open, '-', Close, '&#10;')"/>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You could then write a function to format `Open`/`Close`.

Comment: i got the function from 
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11931481/converting-decimal-hours-to-hours-minutes-and-seconds/11936891#11936891

Answer (score 0):

The XSLT below will do most of the functionality you described. I'm sure it can be made more efficient or better, but it solves the issue of figuring out which days to combine based on open & closing dates.

It does not recaluclate "8.5" as value into "08:30" as hour format.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method='text' indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="OpeningHours">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
    </xsl:template>

 <!-- process if the element is a child of opening hours -->
    <xsl:template match="OpeningHours/*">
        <xsl:choose>

<!-- If the preceding Open or Close is different, or we are the firs element -->
            <xsl:when test="Open != preceding-sibling::*/Open or Close != preceding-sibling::*/Close or position()=1">

        <!-- print out the first 3 characters of the name of the element -->
                <xsl:value-of select='substring(local-name(.),1,3)'/>

            <!-- if the next Open or Close are different -->
                <xsl:if test="Open != following-sibling::*[1]/Open or Close != following-sibling::*[1]/Close or position()=last()">

            <!-- apply templates on "Open" and "Close" elements -->
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
                <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:when>

<!-- if the next Open or Close are diffent -->
            <xsl:when test="Open != following-sibling::*[1]/Open or Close != following-sibling::*[1]/Close">

<!-- print a dash -->
                <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>           

<!-- print 1st 3 leters of the element name *eg; Mon, Tue -->
                <xsl:value-of select='substring(local-name(.),1,3)'/>

<!-- Apply templates on "Open" & "Close" elements -->
                <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
                <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

<!-- when processing open or close elements, just print the value of the content -->
    <xsl:template match="Open">
        <xsl:value-of select='.'/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Close">
        <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select='.'/>
    </xsl:template>


<!-- copy any other node/attribute -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: can you explain a bit what is happening here as im kind of lost.

Comment: This approach seems very cumbersome compared with Martin's use of for-each-group.

Comment: It is.. it's xslt 1.0